# Android custom header with tabs

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to Android development (especially UI aspects).  I'm trying to find a way to include a couple tabs in the header of my Activity.  I would like to put a logo image on the top left of the screen and two tabs to the right of the logo image.  The tabs contents are created from individual Activity's.  How can I go about doing this?

I have tried using a layout with the image on the left and the tabs on the right, but the result is the tab contents are only on the right of the screen (below the tabs and not the image).  I need the contents to use the full width of the screen, not just the space below the tabs.

I have researched creating custom tabs, but have only be able to find ways to customize the look and not the placement.  I need the tabs to be to the right of an image rather than take the full width of the screen.

The only idea I have is to create a custom class that extends ImageView and creates an image for the logo and two tabs.  If this is the best way to do it, how can I use an Activity for the tab contents?  It's easy to launch Activity's when using the standard Android tabs, but I'm not familiar with how to do it from a image.

Thanks in advance for any help.